# Count X and Not X in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table set up like so:

```
column_A |  column_B | column_C |

1        |    any    |     z    |
2        |    and    |     z    |
3        |    all    |     y    |
4        |    please |     b    |
5        |    Help   |     z    |
6        |    with   |     c    |
7        |    this   |     a    |
8        |    query  |     z    |
```

I want to count the occurances of 'z' and not 'z' in this table and display the other variables as well.  So far I have

```
select column_a, column_b, count_c, count(*)
From Generic table
Group By Column_C
```

That will count each of the instances, how can I get it to count not 'z'?

```
ca| cb  | cc | count (c)
-----------------------
1 | any |  z | 4
2 | and |  z | 4
3 | all |  y | 5
4 | pls |  c | 5
5 |Help |  z | 5
6 |with |  c | 5
7 |this |  a | 5
8 |query|  z | 4
```

The above would be the result set that I am looking for.

Comment: Please provide desired results.  What does "count not 'z'" mean?

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN colc=z THEN colc END)as noz,SUM(CASE WHEN colc!=z THEN 0 END)as notz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the number of rows that "match" `column_c`.  The "match" is a bit complicated, because it is either `'z'` or not `'z'`.

The idea is to use the analytic function `count(*)` with a `case` statement:

```
select column_a, column_b, column_c,
       count(*) over (partition by (case when column_c = 'z' then column_c end) as "count(c)" 
From Generic table;
```

The `case` statement divides the rows into the two groups you want, so the appropriate rows are counted.